# How to fix 'User root(user id 0) has been denied access to create application_1558587698997_88549' error while running a sparkjob on server?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a spark job where I am reading data from multiple hadoop files and writing it to a cassandra table. I get the following error when I trigger the spark job:

> org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: User root(user id
>   0)  has been denied access to create application_1558587698997_88549
>     at com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.makeDir(MapRFileSystem.java:1142)     at
>   com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.mkdirs(MapRFileSystem.java:1162)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:1913)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:634)   at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.prepareLocalResources(Client.scala:409)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.createContainerLaunchContext(Client.scala:814)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:173)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.(SparkContext.scala:509)   at
>   org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
>     at
>   com.walmart.labs.back.to.school.TeachersListETLForList.(TeachersListETLForList.java:99)
>     at
>   com.walmart.labs.back.to.school.TeachersListETLForList.main(TeachersListETLForList.java:605)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:759)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119) 
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

When I set the master to local it works, but then I get a out of memory exception as the size of the files is huge. I also tried to set it as below but couldn't fix it.

sparkConf.setMaster("local[4]");

This is my current configuration setting:

sparkConf.setMaster(jobConfig.getString("spark.context-settings.master"));

I want to run it with the same configuration but not sure how to fix this issue.